# Creating a vector(array) of CvSVM vector

Tags: c++, opencv, vector, svm

I want to know to create a vector of "CvSVM" objects. I have tried using:

```
vector<CvSVM> svm_bank;
```

But whenever i use:

```
new_model.train(training_inputs, targets, Mat(), Mat(), svm_params);
svm_bank.push_back(new_model);
```

i get this error:

> c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(593): error C2248: 'CvSVM::CvSVM' : cannot access private member declared in class 'CvSVM'

I use Visual Studio 2013, OpenCV version 2.4.11.

Comment: Did you declare your constructor `private`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. This is modified version of Miki. As Miki's code was compiling but gave a run-time error while the code was being executed.

This solves the problem.

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    vector<Ptr<SVM>> svm_bank;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        Mat trainData;
        Mat responses;

        /*Code for trainingData and 
        responses */

        SVM *new_model;
        new_model = new SVM;
        new_model->train(trainData, responses);

        svm_bank.push_back(new_model);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        Mat samples;
        Mat results;
        svm_bank[i]->predict(samples, results);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

std::vector::push_back will try to call the copy constructor which, as you can see [in the header](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/ddf82d0b154873510802ef75c53e628cd7b2cb13/apps/traincascade/old_ml.hpp), is marked as private.

I would suggest to use emplace_back(), which directly constructs the object when adding it. A constructor overload directly calling train() exists so it's one option.

```
svm_bank.emplace_back(training_inputs, targets, Mat(), Mat(), svm_params);
```